# cube.js - mongodb DBref field inside schema dimension section

Tags: mongodb, cube.js

I am trying to create a filter on DBref id field (mongodb). The SQL query generated is given below

```
SELECT
  `part_r_f_q_dpa`.`partRFQId` `part_r_f_q_dpa__partrfqid`,
  `part_r_f_q_dpa`.`noOfApproval` `part_r_f_q_dpa__noofapproval`,
  `part_r_f_q_dpa`.`CurrentApproved` `part_r_f_q_dpa__currentapprove`
FROM
  makethepart.`directPartApproval` AS `part_r_f_q_dpa`
  LEFT JOIN makethepart.`partRFQ` AS `part_r_f_q` ON `part_r_f_q_dpa`.partRFQId = `part_r_f_q`._id
WHERE
  (`part_r_f_q`.`creatorBuyer.$id` = ?)
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3
ORDER BY
  1 ASC
LIMIT
  10000
```

I am getting an error "Error: Unknown column 'part_r_f_q.creatorBuyer.$id' in 'where clause'".
The code excerpt under dimensions in the schema is as below

```
  creatorbuyer: {
    sql: `${CUBE}.\`creatorBuyer.$id\``,
    type: string
```

can someone please let me know how should we handle the dbrefs ids as shown above

Answer (score 2):

`$id` in Mongo BI is referenced as `_id`. You should use `_id` instead of `$id`.

Comment: I tried changing to      
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`"creatorBuyer._id"\`` but still getting error "Error: Unknown column 'part_r_f_q."creatorBuyer._id"' in 'where clause'"